# How to solve an ImportError: Module "django.middleware.csrf" does not define a "Cs‚rfViewMiddleware" attribute/class

Tags: django, django-models, middleware, django-wsgi

I am working on a django project. After I successfully did the registration and login form, I have logged into the admin panel and shortly after that somehow I got this error:

[image]

[image]
settings.py

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django_filters',
    'startup',
    'vereinsapp',
    'users',
    #'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.Cs‚rfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'startup.wsgi.application'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Anyone know what I could try to fix it? I also tried deleting the apps.py file of 'users'. That is the structure of my project:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the middleware replace this line**

```
'django.middleware.csrf.Cs‚rfViewMiddleware'
```

with below line

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
```